# Hibernate DiscriminatorColumn

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, discriminator

After reading this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199874/about-the-use-of-forcediscriminator-discriminatoroptionsforce-true/46872973#46872973), i'm looking for feedback. In order to let hibernate fill the discriminator column in an InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE strategy beside the use of @DiscriminatorOptions(), the super-class has to be annotated as @Entity and not as @MappedSuperclass

thx for feedback.

Comment: What is your question? single table inheritance is described (as basically everything else) in the user manual. Why not read it? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table

Comment: have i to annotate the super-class with Entity (mandatory) or i can use MappedSuperclass

Comment: With Entity. As documented (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/DiscriminatorColumn.html, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-single-table). MappedSuperclass is not for entity inheritance. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634048/jpa-hibernate-difference-mappedsuperclass-and-entity-abstract-class

Comment: @JBNizet thx alot